# Should Rest API return only structured data? What if I have to get html?

Tags: rest, http, web, restful-url

I'm trying to develop a super simple web page with **REST API**.

In most examples, they suggest to get a resource like below.

request

```
GET /dogs/1
```

response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : bity
}
```

The path `/dogs/1` represents structured data of dog 1. Then which path should I use for the html of dog 1 detail view?

request

```
GET ????
```

response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>name is bity</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then which path should I use for the html

The same.

This is called "content negotiation". The `Accept` request header indicates which *representation* of the same resource the client desires to receive.

See also:

- [REST – Content Negotiation](https://restfulapi.net/content-negotiation/)
- [RFC 7231, section 3.1.1.1, "Media type"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1)
- [Software Engineering: Is it OK to return HTML from a JSON API?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207835/is-it-ok-to-return-html-from-a-json-api)
- [Should I pass a full webpage as html/text for a rest GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396057/should-i-pass-a-full-webpage-as-html-text-for-a-rest-get-call)